# How to autogenerate columns in UWP XAML GridView or ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

In a Windows 10 UWP application I'd like to bind a collection of simple objects to a GridView or ListView and have the GridView or ListView autogenerate the columns based on the properties of the object rather than having to manually declare the columns and {Binding Path=SomePropertyName} on a TextBlock in the XAML.

This doesn't look possible.. is it?

Is there a different type of control other than GridView or ListView that will allow this behaviour?

Note: This is not WPF

Comment: Hi Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR: This is not possible out of the box with the `GridView` or `ListView` controls.*

In UWP a `GridView` is:

> A control that displays data items in rows and columns.

[image: GridView]

The `ListView` is quite similar but only shows the items stacked in 1 dimension, by default vertical.

The `DataGrid` control (what this is typically called) is currently (as of SDK build 14393) not available in the default control set. With "some" effort you could write your own control for this behavior.

There are however multiple 3rd party solutions available, just google/bing for UWP DataGrid. Here are some of them:

- [MyToolkit.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyToolkit.Extended) NuGet package, more info on their [GitHub](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid) page.

Libraries that might need a paid subscription/license:

- [SyncFusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/sfdatagrid)
- [ComponentOne](http://our.componentone.com/2016/06/22/flexgrid-a-stable-fast-flexible-uwp-data-grid/)
- [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/universal-windows-platform/grids)

You might find even more alternatives.

Comment: Thanks bart for confirming that it is not possible using any of the currently available 'out of the box' controls that ship with the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Can you write it in c# instead of xaml? Maybe it would be possible then, as long as you can access the container (gridview or whatever you use) beyond the constructor of your class. I'm not entirely sure if you can generate a new grid and switch on the fly but you could test it easily.

Comment: So you mean create the control in the code behind, use reflection to look at the properties on each object in the list and programatically add rows and columns? 
I considered this but hoped there was a control that could autogenerate columns like there has previously been in WinForms and I think WPF.

Comment: Yes exactly. Im not entirely sure if its possible, I'm only familiar with xamarin.forms for android/iOS. I do think it is possible with those two.